# AWS Serverless .NET Project local run with Docker image fails

Tags: .net, lambda, serverless

I have a problem running my first serverless project based on AWS Lambda. Im trying to run API using SAM CLI on localhost, still geting

```
Error: AspNetCoreFunction failed to build: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat bin/Release/lambda-publish: file does not exist
```

while executing

```
sam build --template .\serverless.template
```

from my Catalog.API project.
I can't find solution reading documentation or searching Google.
Please check my solution placed at: https://github.com/RazorN/Serverless-aws-e-shop/tree/catalog-init

My goal is to run localy API using "sam local start-api"

Also, please share any thoughts about my solution architecture or local testing method, as I said it's my first attepmt  to serverless architecture after working with microservices.

Thanks for any asnwers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add to your `Catalog.API.csproj` next lines:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
      <OutputPath>bin/Release/lambda-publish</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

And build your solution in `Release` mode.

Or fix your docker file (`Serverless-aws-e-shop/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Dockerfile`) to copy files from existing path  or use multi-stage build to build your solution inside a container ([as example dotnet docker app does](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/complexapp/Dockerfile))